# Not able to upload file to web server

Tags: php, mysql, file, file-upload

When I change the target directory from (relative?) "bilder/" to (absolute?) "/var/www/html/test/bilder/" I'm not able to upload files anymore from my computer to the web server. Anyone know what the problem might be?

I get no error from:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)){ 
   echo "Success!";
} 
else { 
   echo "Error!";
}
```

Comment: More info please. What is `$target`? What exactly is not working and what error do you receive? A simple "it is not working anymore" is not enough.

Comment: It's probably not the same folder?

Comment: how do you know it doesn't work if you get no error?

Comment: check for  structure of directory in server and permission

Comment: I tried deleting all the content in folder "bilder" then i changed the target directory to "/var/www/html/test/bilder/" and nothing gets saved in "bilder" anymore

Comment: If that really is the only difference (I doubt that), then you have specified two different folders. But a general note: typically it is not a good idea to keep uploaded data within the document root where the web server can reach it. Either you have to restrict access afterwards (error prone and annoying) or you have a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some below reasons, which occurs frequently :

1. enctype should be included in **form** tag i.e.

   ```
   <form method='' name='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   ```
2. Target Path should be correct.
3. Directory may not have proper permissions.
4. Images size is more than default uploaded size.

Answer (score 0):

```
//select folder name perfectly
 $path = "image/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
 $file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to change the **mode** of **www** directory recursively (i.e. command will apply to all subfiles and subfolders), this is done by the following command at terminal:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www
```

if the above method would not work try this:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var
```

also remove the "forward slash" from your absolute path "/var/www/html/test/bilder/", this should be like this **/var/www/html/test/bilder**

Comment: 2014-03-03 12:40:00 Failed to connect to servername: Network error: Connection refused

Comment: Try with previous settings, also try this: "sudo chmod 775 -R /var/www"

Comment: You can also try changing the OWNER with "chown" command, see the link http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/

Comment: well i cant enter putty or winscp anymore because of your first advice

Comment: Actually that was related to folder and file permission, putty and winscp are for remote login changing mode and owner I don't think any thing could do with remote login utilites like putty or winscp.